# Layout problem message

Tags: errors, miktex

I get the following message, when I try to open a .tex file, after installing updates on my miktex 2.9:

> A problem occured while laying out the loaded document in the editor.
>   This is caused by an issue in the underlying Qt framework and can
>   cause TeXworks to crash under certain circumstances. The symptoms of
>   this problem are hidden or overlapping lines. To work around this,
>   please try one of the following:   -) Turn syntax highlighting off and
>   on   -) Turn  line numbers off and on  -) Resize the windows
>
> We are sorry for the inconvenience.

I tried both resizing the window and turning syntax coloring, but it didn't help. Overall i'm having a lot of issues, since the update. I can't even open a single file, without immediate crash of the program. Also, typing anything gives no visible result. I tried reinstalling, but the problems persist. What's going on?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Win XP Home edition SP3

Comment: I think this is really off-topic. It needs to be asked on TeXworks forums or reported as a bug against the editor or MikTeX. The issue has nothing to do with TeX per se and it is unlikely we'll be able to suggest a solution for a bug which crashes the editor. Aside from general, non-TeX specific advice such as deleting your existing preferences, reinstalling (which you've done), making sure MikTeX is up-to-date etc., there's really not much to be said. There will, however, be things to be said if this is asked in a more appropriate place.... (At least, there certainly should be....)

Comment: Can the TeXworks developers really not spell?